# How do I remove a special character in a file?

Tags: vi, special-characters

I had to use OCR to get the text of a very large script I did not want to type by hand.

I have multiple lines like this

```
echo "<91>ps <97>eF|grep...
```

It should read;

```
echo "`ps -eF|grep...
```

Even with ":set list" the only thing I see is <91> and <97>

I tried this and other ASCII characters to insert the back quote:

```
sed -e 's/'$(echo "97")'/`/g'
```

to no avail.

Either I'm doing this all wrong or using the wrong control values.

Can you suggest something else?

Comment: what does `hexdump` or `xxd` show for the relevant contents of the script?

Comment: 0000002896  | ".ps .eF|grep "|

Comment: Are they periods?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like cp1252 (or similar).  See *[What characters do not directly map from Cp1252 to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324622/what-characters-do-not-directly-map-from-cp1252-to-utf-8)*.  Use [recode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014069/windows-1252-to-utf-8-encoding/4490957#4490957) to repair it...

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately recode isn't available on my system (neither is installing it)